# Error while running the zookeeper command on windows machine

Tags: windows, apache-zookeeper

I am getting the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect." while running the zookeeper command on my windows machine.

```
C:\sreevani\ApacheKafka\confluent-community-7.6.0\confluent-7.6.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: Why do you have 4 dots before \etc?

Comment: Its actually the below: 

C:\sreevani\ApacheKafka\confluent-community-7.6.0\confluent-7.6.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties
The syntax of the command is incorrect

Comment: Try `.\zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\etc\kafka\zookeeper.properties`.

Comment: Its still givng the same error. Could you please give the full command here